# Qtranslate + Woocommerce (multiple tinymce)

Tags: customization, plugins, tinymce

I am using WooCommerce and qTranslate to develop an ecommerce website. I run into the following problems. I've googled it and days of trying to no avail.

On the top of the product edit pages, the tinyMCE text area looks ok. It has several languages tabs along with visual and text editor tabs. However, at the bottom, the TinyMCE box for Short Description isn't integrated well with the qTranslate. The tool bar of it doesn't show up and there is no language tabs neither.

Additionally, switching between the visual and text editor tabs is not working properly. A workaround I found on the Internet is to refresh the page every time. But it is not a solution.

Apart from the problems above, every time the page refreshes, it seems that the cursor focuses in the box of the Short Description. If the Short Description is at the last section of the product edit page, the page will automatically scroll to where it is after reloading.

I also tried to install TinyMCE Advanced and Ultimate TinyMCE to see if these two plugins can fix the problems, but also no luck.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

Do you absolutely have to use qTranslate to do it?

If not, read the official documentation for recommended method of translation:
http://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-localization/

Also try any plugin that is made to integrate with WooCommerce such as WPML.

Fixing compatibility between two plugins that is not integrated is not really worth the trouble. They are going to be updated continuously and you have to keep making changes to make them work together.

Answer (score -2):

Ok, so I was searching for a solution like crazy and finally found a – temporary – solution. After re-installing every single plugin and theme without success, I was almost giving up.

If your button “Visual” in the editor isnt working/responding anymore, after installing Woocommerce, try this:

via ftp, (make a backup first) open the file:

```
/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/admin/class-wc-admin-editor.php
```

go to line 55 which looks like this:

```
$arr['wc_shortcodes_button'] = WC()->plugin_path() .‘/assets/js/admin/editor_plugin_lang.php’;
```

and comment (put `/**` before and `*/` after) the line like this:

```
/**
$arr['wc_shortcodes_button'] = WC()->plugin_path() . ‘/assets/js/admin/editor_plugin_lang.php’;
*/
```

Save and upload. Open a page/post and you should be fine. Hopefully!

Comment: NO NO NO, never make any changes to core/plugin or theme files that you are not the author of, NEVER

Comment: Ok, didnt know that. It was just an agony and I had to do something to get things going. Is there any way to reproduce the desired effect without touching the original file? Say, putting that line in a different file?

Comment: There should be an alternative method. I haven't worked with these plugins, so best will be is to contact their support for assistance